# Ffmpeg - Add image and watermark

Tags: ffmpeg

I am able to add a watermark to my video using the following command:

```
overlay=(main_w/2)-(overlay_w/2):main_h-overlay_h
```

I was wondering is it possible to add an image to show for 3 seconds to the start of every video as well as add a watermark to the video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Just add another [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) and include the [enable](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing) option.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i image1.jpg -i image2.png -filter_complex
  "[0:v][1:v]overlay[bg];
   [bg][2:v]overlay=enable='lte(t,3)'"
  output.mp4
```

Refer to the [list of accepted functions](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation).

Comment: Thanks @LordNeckbeard - would it be possible to supply a full sample command for this?

Comment: @Damien Sure. Updated the answer. I previously provided only a simple example because I did not know your actual `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: Thanks @LordNeckbeard - last question. This commands works well. Is it possible to show image2.png for 3 seconds, then load the video with the watermark? This command shows image2.png for 3 seconds then image1.jpg as an overlay

Comment: @Damo Sorry, but I don't really understand what you want to do.

Comment: I wanted to have a 3 second intro - play the video and that video would have a watermark on it. I have been able to do this and the command is ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -framerate 25 -t 3 -i 1920x1080_intro.png -i DSC_0002.MOV -i watermark_color.png -report -an -filter_complex "[1][2]overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/2,setsar=1[v];[0]setsar=1[pre];[pre][v]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0" ../testing/videoWithIntroAndWatermark.mp4

Comment: @Damo Ok. I didn't see that you [re-asked at the site for programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47652586/1109017) until now.

Comment: won't this eat the first seconds of the video?

Comment: @Toolkit No....